# how to disable break indent of a long for-statement?

Tags: clang-format

```
    for(my_struct_t *s = users; s != NULL; s = (my_struct_t *)(s->hh.next)) {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", s->id, s->name);
    }
```

The above code is indented to the following style by the following command. I'd like to keep the original style so that for-statement is always in the same line. Is there a way to do so in `clang-format`?

```
$ clang-format -style='{IndentWidth: 8, UseTab: Always, SpaceBeforeParens: Never, IndentCaseLabels: true }'
```

```
    for(my_struct_t *s = users; s != NULL;
        s = (my_struct_t *)(s->hh.next)) {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", s->id, s->name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `for`-statement is kept on one line, then (given your input and style options) the line extends to column 81. By default the `ColumnLimit` is 80. So you can do one of these:

- Set `ColumnLimit` to 81 or larger
- Set `ColumnLimit` to 0 (indicating that no lines should not be broken due to column limit)
- Surround the `for`-statement with `// clang-format on` and `// clang-format off` to disable formatting
- Let `clang-format` split the `for`-statement into multiple lines.

See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more details about `ColumnLimit`.